# What is the (undocumented?) Object.Value in .NET?

Tags: .net, object

Where does the undocumented Object.Value come from in .NET?

Is it a method or a property?  What is its purpose?

When I write something like (VB.NET WinForms... haven't tried C#):

```
TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value
```

I get an error:

```
Option Strict On disallows late binding.
```

However, without Option Strict On, it seems to simply return the value of the object.

Any documentation or explanation of 'Value' in the context of the Object class?

** This question isn't about the error.  That's used as an example for context.  It's about what is the Value method/property of the object class? **

Comment: Is that ASP.NET? If yes: ListItem is well documented. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

Comment: Yes, -1: You did not even write if it's ASP.NET or something else. The code snippet is very little.

Comment: And why to you think object has a Value property?

Comment: @CSE - The question is about the .NET Object Class and the Value method that seems to be undocumented.  It's not specific to VB.NET or C# or F# or ASP.NET...

Comment: @CSE - That's my question.  If I can just put ".Value" on any object then it must be a method or property *or* there must some other valid explanation, of which I am seeking.  I see absolutely no reason for downvotes.

Comment: No, you cannot. As i have said: Object has no Value property.

Comment: Your problem is that while yes, your question is about the base .net Object type, you are using it in the context of something else (in this case I think it's Windows Forms).  That's what's cofusing people, since SelectedItem in Asp.net is not an object type, it's a ListItem type, and people think you're being stupid.

Comment: Actually, the question *IS* about the error, because there is no undocumented Value property on Object.  You have simply jumped to the wrong conclusion (that this must mean Value is undocumented), and explaining the error corrects your misunderstanding.

Comment: @CSE - Just saying 'No, you cannot' doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @Mystere Man - I'm still searching for documentation on that 'dynamic object/property support'.  The best example so far is Philips answer.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, there is no property or method named Value in Object.

The way VB.NET handles `Object.Value` is apparently specific to that language.
In C#, for instance, the following code will not even compile:

```
 Object o=new Object();
 Console.WriteLine(o.Value);
```

with this error:

"'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Note that this has nothing to do with late binding.

In VB.NET, on the other hand, the following code *will* compile without `Option Strict`:

```
 Dim o As New Object()
 Console.WriteLine(o.Value)
```

but will output a warning: "Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur."

That code will indeed fail at runtime:

"Public member 'Value' on type 'Object' not found."

VB.NET allowed the code above to compile because it adds extra method calls to the method, as can be seen when we decompile the program:

```
object o = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(new object());
Console.Write(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(NewLateBinding.LateGet(o, null, "Value", new object[0], null, null, null)));
Console.Write(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(NewLateBinding.LateGet(o, null, "Value", new object[0], null, null, null)));
```

Note that LateGet supports the late binding feature of VB.NET.  It checks whether the given object really does have a `Value` property.  If it does, it gets the Value property and returns that value for Console.Write to output.  `Object` itself doesn't have `Value`, but other objects do, such as `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<T>`.

The [LateGet method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding.lateget.aspx)
of the [NewLateBinding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding.aspx) "[e]xecutes a late-bound property get or field access call".  We can dissect the arguments of LateGet like so:

```
o,  // Instance of the object with the property
null,  // Type (not used)
"Value", // Name of the property
new object[0], // No arguments
null,  // No argument names
null,  // No type arguments ('Value' is not generic)
null   // N/A; used only on methods with ByRef parameters
```

The [RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.getobjectvalue.aspx)
boxes the given object, and is thus less relevant here.

In C#, late binding can be achieved using code like the following:

```
var o=new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,int>(0,1);
Console.WriteLine("{0}",o.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(o,new object[]{}));
```

I use `KeyValuePair` here because it contains a `Value` property.  If it were just an `Object` the code will compile, but will fail at runtime with a NullReferenceException because `Value` doesn't exist in `Object`.  The code gets the object's type, gets the PropertyInfo associated with the property "Value", and gets the value from the object and the PropertyInfo.  `LateGet` most likely uses a very similar technique.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Now we're gettin somewhere.

Comment: Nice Peter. Thanks again.  Don't know why your question was downvoted.  Let me know if you find any documentation on this subject, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no .Value on Object.

When you turn `Option Strict` to `Off`, you allow VB.Net to dynamically invoke methods and properties.   Why `.Value` seems to work for you isn't because Object has that property, but because *the object you assigned* to `SelectedItem` has a `.Value` property

Try this

```
Option Strict Off

Module Module1

    Public Class tst
        Public Value As Integer = 5
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As Object
        a = New tst()
        Console.WriteLine(a.Value)
        a = New List(Of Integer)()
        Console.WriteLine(a.Value)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that the first writeline works writing out "5", but the second one throws an exception because `List<>` doesn't have a .Value property.

Comment: Hey Thanks for taking the time to explain in a clear rational fashion.  FWIW, I'm still searching for more documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Late binding means that the method of a subclass over rides the method of a parent class.  (Or, the same can be said with properties.)

In this case, I'm assuming that SelectedItem is an instance of a subclass of Object, but the reference to it that ListBox1 has is an Object instance.  This means that without late binding, Object's Value property will be checked.

So, you should try casting SelectedItem to the type that it actually is.

(Disclaimer: I'm not a VB person.  I'm basing this all off of the wording of the error message and my understanding of how inheritance binding typically works.)

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question of what the Value method/property is.

Comment: Well, no.  It's likely that in VB that every class extends Object and that every class has a Value property.  It would not make sense to document that other than "Overriden in each subclass" because the Value property in ClassA and the Value property in ClassB could mean vastly different things.

Comment: The problem is that ListBox.SelectItem *is* of Type System.Object no matter what language you are using, I don't see any subclassing.  I'm just using VB.NET as an example.  You still haven't clearly explained what you believe .Value to be.

Comment: @Juxtaposition - ListBox.SelectedItem is only of type System.Object in Windows Forms.  In asp.net, it's of type ListItem.  I would also think WPF also has it's own type for that.  So your causing confusing by trying to be simple.

Comment: @Juxtaposition: It does now, since you edited it.  It did not originally, and frankly, that's a bit rude to suggest that it always said something, when you added it later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Value property on Object in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

What you are seeing is dynamic object support, which lets you create new properties on anything you want without declaring them.

Your code is basically trying to do is declare a "Value" object (that is currently uninitialized) on SelectedItem (which in Windows Forms is delcared as an object). Since there is no Value property, it thinks you want to create one.

`Option Strict On` does not allow types to be dynamically created without being declared, so that's why you see the error. In effect, .NET is stopping you from shooting yourself in the foot, and telling you.. no... there is no Value property. And this is a prime example of why `Option Strict On` is such a good thing.

To illustrate my point, try changing the code to this:

```
ListBox1.SelectedItem.Supercalifragilisticexpialadocious
```

You'll get the same error. Also, read the third paragraph under Remarks in *[Option Strict Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: Any references for this "Dynamic Object Support"?

Comment: @Juxtaposition - That's how VB has always worked, you didn't have to declare objects, and they can be used simply by referencing them.  If you reference a non-existing object, it creates it.  That's what Option Strict On is designed to prevent.

Comment: @Juxtaposition - Any efforts by your own? Did you even try to google for option strict in VB?

Comment: @Mystere Man - True.  Can you provide a reference such that I can read about this magic?

Comment: @Mystere Man - Sure.  I'm trying to find some documentation that speaks about dynamic properties and VB.NET.